# Evaluating a finite summation

Tags: summation

What is the general formula for the following sum:

$$\sum^N_{n=1}\frac{n+1}{n}$$

where $N$ is a finite natural number.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{n}$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{(1+\frac{1}{n})}=N+H_N$$ where $H_N$ is the N-th harmonic number. Unfortunately there’s no closed form for this sum, just we know that it is asymptotic to $N+\log{N}$